# External sharing for selected libraries

Tags: online, sharing, external

As far I know it is not possible to allow external sharing of selectd libraries only. I know I can control external sharing on collection level, but say I have a collection with a number of sub sites. On each subsite I want the users to be able to share externally, but ONLY selected libraries - and by no means should it be possible to share the entire site.

Would that be possible in any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

the only thing you can do is limit the permission of the specific libraries to be shared by the people.
check here for the exact permissions you need: [Understanding permission levels in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/understanding-permission-levels-in-sharepoint-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848)

Comment: That doesn't solve the potential risk of people sharing the entire site with external users.

Comment: you are correct, I would recommend you to move the libraries if possible with a migration tool like shareGate to a different place and link the relevant user to the links.

Comment: Yeah that was what I was ending up as well. Would like to not have to replicate datas, but it seems theres no way to avoid that.